# How does python import order affect names?

Tags: python, import, module, flask

I'm doing a flask tutorial (http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) and I came upon a behaviour that I couldn't explain.
The main directory structure of the tutorial is :

```
microblog
|
|---- app 
|     |---- __init__.py
|     |---- views.py  
|
|---- flask  
|---- run.py
```

and the contents of the files are :

#### microblog/run.py

```
#!flask/bin/python

from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

#### microblog/app/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

#### microblog/app/views.py

```
from app import app

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")

def index():
    return "Hello World!"
```

everything works but if I transpose these two lines:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

in views.py and then I execute run.py I get:

> ImportError: cannot import name app

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're trying to import from the newly created variable `app`.  If you want to import variable modules, then use `importlib` package:

```
my_module = importlib.import_module(app, 'view')
```

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what the other answer says, this is a circular import problem. `app.__init__` tries to import `app.views`, which tries to import the `app.app` `Flask` created in `app.__init__`. If the `Flask` is created before `app.__init__` imports `app.views`, `app.views` finds `app.app`. If the `Flask` is created after the import, it isn't there yet when `app.views` tries to find it.

Circular imports cause all sorts of horrible problems. It might be difficult, but the best way to handle them is generally to reorganize your code so there aren't circular imports.

Comment: I would also suggest to not name files and variables with the same name, if you have file/module with the name app containing variable app, it's only matter of time. Declare each filename/module/varialble its own unique name, that way its much easier to debug.